not able to docker:exec and start my tomcat in same command
I've been trying to start my Tomcat server and run a mvn exec command as a CMD statement in my Dockerfile, but I'm running into the following error, and not able to figure it out:
Error: Could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher

Here's my dockerfile:
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-11-slim AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN mvn clean package


RUN mvn --version # Runs fine


FROM tomcat:10-jdk11

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/target/project.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/project.war

EXPOSE 8080

CMD mvn exec:java -Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false -Dexec.mainClass="MyClass" && catalina.sh run

I've tried many things but still not able to figure it out.

You have to create a file named start.sh like follow:
/bin/bash

mvn exec:java -Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false -Dexec.mainClass="MyClass" && catalina.sh run

Then, change the Dockerfile as follow:
FROM maven:3.8.5-openjdk-11-slim AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN mvn clean package


RUN mvn --version # Runs fine


FROM tomcat:10-jdk11

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/target/project.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/project.war

COPY start.sh .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD start.sh

